# Show log and System.out.println in a new console created in a Java application

Tags: java, runtime, exec

I've an application in java where I use the method `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("a command")` to execute some shell commands.

In `a command` I try to execute an OSGI application.

I would like to start a new console and print the classical log and `System.out.println` in this console.

Someone could tell me how can I do that? Thank you in advance!

Comment: That's several steps.  Which one is giving you errors?

Comment: I don't get any error. Logs and System.out.println are printed in the Eclipse console. Anyway, my application will be launched outside Eclipse and I want to see these logs and information in a console ad hoc.

Comment: So which part is giving you problems?   Write a short self-contained example (SSCE) that demonstrates your issue.  StackOverflow is very good with simple straightforward questions like that.   Requests like yours are so broad your question is likely to be closed without ever getting you any help.